# how to to JSONify the code defined in typescript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

Is there a way to JSONify the code defined in typescript?

```
export type ArticleList = ArticleListItem[];

export class ArticleListItem {
  title!: string;
  date?: string;
  key_type!: KeyTypes;
  path!: string;
  query: string = '';

  constructor( item: ArticleListItem ) {
    Object.assign( this, item );
  }
}
```

I would like to change the above typescript code to JSON.

Comment: Do you mean Object of class ArticleListItem into JSON?

Comment: @SpursP Yes, I want to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.stringify(new ArticleListitem('x'))` method to get the json.
Refer - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify